How do you access images at a URL from within the JNI?
I am working on a project that involves matching images on an android phone using local resources.  A general overview of the workflow is to take a camera image, generate a locality sensitive hash for it, find it's nearest neighbors from a hash table of potential matches, and then narrow down those neighbors to a single best match using ORB feature matching.  I am stuck on the last step.
Most of the heavy lifting is being done with C++ through the JNI in order to improve performance, and since one of the main reasons I opted to do it this way was to use native OpenCV, I really don't want to be doing my matches on the Java side, but I also don't want to either be passing 10+ images at a time across the interop boundary or be saving 10+ images at a time to provide a local file reference.
All of the images for potential matches are available online, so what I'd like to be able to do ideally is to only pass/save the query image and access the potential matches via their URLs.  Doing this on the java side would be trivial but I can't seem to crack how to make it work from the JNI, so, after banging my head on this for a while, I figured I'd defer to the wisdom of the internet.  How do I open an image at a URL from within the JNI?
I think my google fu might be a little weak on this one.  Everything I've been able to find on the subject has either been a general "how to pass an image to the JNI", stuff like URLMon that saves the image as a file, or image-from-URL stuff in a C++ for Windows/Linux context that I'm not sure will work in this context.  When it comes to getting an image from a URL, analyzing it, and throwing it in the trash, all from the JNI, on the other hand, that doesn't seem be something many tutorials have been written for.

"the JNI" is just a C/C++ library (or whatever language you use for developing it) plus an API for accessing Java objects. Passsing an URL (thus a string) from Java to JNI isn't a big problem, therefore your question seems to be: "How do I download a file in C or C++".

Downloading a file directly in C/C++ within a JNI (Java Native Interface) environment for Android is not recommended due to security limitations and complexity.

Alright, finally got it to work.  If anyone else is facing this same issue this is how I handled it.  Curl with openssl is the simplest way to handle this under normal circumstances, but getting curl and openssl loaded into the JNI is a bit of a pain, especially working in windows and WSL is no help on this one.  Fortunately, prefabs are available for both of these libraries.
To use the prebuilt libraries, first modify your app's build.gradle file with the following (note that this is in groovy to make everything play nice with the gradle files of the opencv libraries that were already imported in the normal 'build locally and import' way.  Haven't tested any of this in kotlin.):

add the following dependencies:
implementation "com.android.ndk.thirdparty:openssl:1.1.1l-beta-1"
implementation "com.android.ndk.thirdparty:curl:7.79.1-beta-1"


under buildFeatures, set prefab to true:
buildFeatures {
   prefab = true
}


Add the argument "-DANDROID_STL=c++_shared" to defaultConfig.externalNativeBuild.cmake.  Note that there are two externalNativeBuild.cmake options available.  Make sure this is the one under defaultConfig, where your flags and arguments are, and not under android, where your cmake path and version are.
cmake {
         cppFlags "-frtti -fexceptions"
         abiFilters "x86", "x86_64", "arm64-v8a", "arm64-v8a"
         arguments "-DOpenCV_DIR=opencv/native", "-DANDROID_STL=c++_shared"
      }


Add the following to your CMakeLists.txt:
find_package(curl REQUIRED CONFIG)
target_link_libraries(${CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME} curl::curl)



Don't include openssl here.  Curl will link it automatically and it's already in the CMakeLists generated when curl gets added.
Now you should be able to include curl/curl.h as normal and make your web requests from the JNI directly:
    #include <curl/curl.h>
    #include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
    #include <vector>

    CURL *curl = curl_easy_init();
    const char *myURL = "https://my_image.is_here.jpg";
    std::vector<uchar> stream;

    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, myURL);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, write_data);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, &stream);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
    CURLcode res = curl_easy_perform(curl);

    if (res == CURLE_OK){
        cv::Mat img = cv::imdecode(stream, cv::IMREAD_GRAYSCALE);

        //do stuff with img

        img.release();
    }
    else {
        message = curl_easy_strerror(res);
    }

    curl_easy_cleanup(curl);

"write_data" is a local function that writes to the stream:
    size_t write_data(char *ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void  *userdata)
    {
        std::vector<uchar> *stream = (std::vector<uchar>*)userdata;
        size_t count = size * nmemb;
        stream->insert(stream->end(), ptr, ptr + count);
        return count;
    }

